# how can make one user can login from one computer use Codeignaiter

Tags: codeigniter

a won to check is user already login once can't login from different computer with same username, if is logout then hi can login from different computer. i Use codeignaiter and ion-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Easily Do This Via Database query . Create an new field user_isactive in user table where you store user id and password . 
When user logged in on that time makes  user_isactive=1 . 
And your username password query which is use for check the id password having condition where  user_isactive=0

if that is user is logged in then it's return false . and other user can't be logged in at same time